# $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3 t^2+1} {\rm exp}\left(\frac{at^2+ibt}{3 t^2+1}+itx\right){\rm d}t$

Tags: integration, special-functions, bessel-functions, hypergeometric-function, error-function

How to solve the integral?

$$
f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3 t^2+1} {\rm exp}\left(\frac{a t^2+i b t}{3 t^2+1}+itx\right){\rm d}t\tag{1}
\\{\rm with}\,\, x,b\in \mathbb{R},a\in\mathbb{R}_{<0},i^2=-1$$

This question was previously [posted](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/262473/69288) in Mathematica SE, however algorithms of Mathematica couldn't solve it. A deeper mathematical analysis is needed. In the solution a potpourri of Error function, Bessel function, hypergeometric function or infinite series of them can be expected (see these solved similar integrals: [integral1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4337936/737314), [integral2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4354375/737314), [integral3](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4358865/737314)).

A plot of $f(x)$ for $a=-200,b=-100$:

[image]

Comment: It seems to be possible to compute the integral using residue theorem; did you try this method?

Comment: i would try bring it to one exponent, means summ of expressions, and then feymanns technique, since you have external parameter x here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Useful integral.}}$

Denote
$$f(k,m,x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac {t^k}{(3t^2+1)^{m+k+1}}\,e^{itx} \,\text dt\tag1$$
Are known the integrals via the modified Bessel function
$$f(0,m,x)=\sqrt{\dfrac\pi3}\,\dfrac{2}{m!}\,\left|\dfrac x{2\sqrt3}\right|^{m+\frac12}\operatorname K_{\large-\frac12-m}\left(\dfrac{|x|}{\sqrt3}\right),\tag2$$
$$f(1,m,x)=i\,\sqrt{\dfrac\pi3}\,\dfrac{x}{3(m+1)!} \,\left|\dfrac x{2\sqrt3}\right|^{m+\frac12}\operatorname K_{\large-\frac12-m}\left(\dfrac{|x|}{\sqrt3}\right)=\dfrac{ix}{6m+6}\,f(0,m,x).\tag3$$

Besides,
$$f(k+2, m,x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac {t^{k+2}}{(3t^2+1)^{m+k+3}}\,e^{itx} \,\text dt
=\dfrac13\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac {(3t^2+1-1)\,t^k}{(3t^2+1)^{m+k+3}}\,e^{itx} \,\text dt,$$
$$f(k+2,m,x)=\dfrac13\big(f(k,m+1,x)-f(k,m+2,x)\big),$$
$$f(k+4,m,x)=\dfrac19\big(f(k,m+2,x)-2f(k,m+3,x)+f(k,m+4,x)\big),$$
$$f(2k,m,x)=\dfrac1{3^k}\sum\limits_{j=0}^k (-1)^j\dbinom k{j}f(0,m+k+j,x).\tag4$$
$$f(2k+1,m,x)=\dfrac{ix}{3^k}\sum\limits_{j=0}^k \dfrac{(-1)^j}
{6(m+k+j+1)} \dbinom k{j}f(0,m+k+j,x).\tag5$$

In the Matematika language,
$$\begin{align}
&f(k,n+k+1,x)=\dfrac1{2\Gamma[1+k+n]}3^{-1-k} \bigg(3^{\large\frac12+\frac k2} \big(1+(-1)^k\big) \Gamma\left[\frac12+\frac k2\right]\\[4pt]
&\times \Gamma\left[\frac12+\frac k2+n\right]
\,\operatorname{HypergeometricPFQ}\left[\left\{\frac12+\frac k2\right\},\left\{\frac12,\frac12-\frac k2-n\right\},\frac{x^2}{12}\right]\\[4pt]
&-I\, 3^{\large \frac k2} \big(-1+(-1)^k\big)\, x\, \Gamma\left[1+\frac k2\right]\, \Gamma\left[\frac k2+n\right]\\[4pt] &\times\operatorname{HypergeometricPFQ}\left[\left\{1+\frac k2\right\},\left\{\frac32,1-\frac k2-n\right\},\frac{x^2}{12}\right]\\[4pt]
&+2\, I\, 3^{-n} |x|^{1+k+2 n} \Gamma[-1-k-2 n] \Gamma[1+k+n]\\[4pt] &\times\operatorname{HypergeometricPFQ}\left[\{1+k+n\},\left\{1+\frac k2+n,\frac32+\frac k2+n\right\},\frac{x^2}{12}\right]\\[4pt]
&\times \left(\big(-1+(-1)^k\big) \cos\left[\frac {k\pi}2+n\pi\right] \operatorname{Sign}[x]+I \big(1+(-1)^k\big) \sin\left[\frac {k\pi}2+n\pi\right]\right)\bigg)\\
& \,\text{if}\; x\in\mathbb R\;\&\&\;\Re[k]>-1\;\&\&\;\Re[k+2 n]>-2
\end{align}\tag{$\Diamond$}$$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Integration.}}$

$$I=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{1}{3t^2+1}\,\exp\,\dfrac{at^2+ibt}{3t^2+1}\,\,e^{itx} \,\text dt$$
$$=\exp\,\dfrac a3\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{1}{3t^2+1}\,\exp\left(-\dfrac{a}{3(3t^2+1)}\right)\exp\,\dfrac{ibt}{3t^2+1}\,\,e^{itx} \,\text dt$$
$$=\exp\,\dfrac a3 \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac1{n!}\left(-\dfrac a3\right)^n \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(ib)^k}{k!} 
\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\,\dfrac {t^k}{(3t^2+1)^{n+k+1}}\,e^{itx} \,\text dt,$$
$$I=\dfrac1{\sqrt3}\exp\,\dfrac a3 \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac1{n!}\left(-\dfrac a3\right)^n \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\left(-\dfrac13\right) ^{\large\genfrac\lfloor\rfloor{}{}{k+1}2}x^{^{\Large2\genfrac\{\}{}{}k2}} \,\dfrac{b^k}{k!}$$
$$\times \operatorname B\left(\genfrac\lfloor\rfloor{}{}{k+1}2+\dfrac12,n-\genfrac\lfloor\rfloor{}{}{1-k}2+\dfrac12\right)$$
$$\times\operatorname{_1F_2}\left(\genfrac\lfloor\rfloor{}{}{k+1}2+\dfrac12;\,\dfrac12+2\genfrac\{\}{}{}k2,\,\genfrac\lfloor\rfloor{}{}{1-k}2+\dfrac12-n;\dfrac{x^2}{12}\right),$$
and these approximations do not provide sufficient accuracy.

$\color{brown}{\mathbf{Alternative\ approach,\ case\; x=0.}}$

Since
$$g(k)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{(-a+3ibt)^k}{(3t^2+1)^{k+1}}\,\text dt
=\sqrt{\dfrac\pi3}\,\dfrac{\Gamma\left(k+\frac12\right)}{k!}(-a)^k
\operatorname{_2F_1}\left(\frac{1-k}2,-\frac k2;\frac12-k;\frac{3b^2}{a^2}\right),$$
then
$$I\bigg|_{x=0}=\sqrt{\dfrac\pi3}\,\exp\dfrac a3\,\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{\Gamma\left(k+\frac12\right)}{k!^2}\left(-\frac a3\right)^k \operatorname{_2F_1} \left(\frac{1-k}2,-\frac k2;\frac12-k;\frac{3b^2}{a^2}\right).$$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Alternative approach, common case.}}$

$$I=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{1}{3t^2+1}\,\exp\,\dfrac{at^2+ibt}{3t^2+1}\,\,e^{itx} \,\text dt$$
$$=\exp\,\dfrac a3\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{1}{3t^2+1}\,\exp\left(-\dfrac{a}{3(3t^2+1)}\right)\exp\,\dfrac{ibt}{3t^2+1}\,\,e^{itx} \,\text dt$$
$$=\exp\,\dfrac a3 \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{a^n}{n!} \left(-\dfrac13\right)^n\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(ib)^{2k}}{(2k)!} 
\left(f(2k,n,x)+\dfrac{ib}{2k+1}\,f(2k+1,n.x)\right)$$
$$=2\sqrt{\dfrac\pi3}\exp\,\dfrac a3 \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{a^n}{n!} \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{b^{2k}}{(2k)!}\,\left(-
\dfrac13\right)^{n+k} 
\sum\limits_{j=0}^k \dfrac{(-1)^j}{(n+k+j)!}\dbinom k{j}$$
$$\times\left(1-\dfrac{bx}{6(2k+1)(n+k+j+1)}\right)
\left|\dfrac x{2\sqrt3}\right|^{n+k+j+\frac12}
\operatorname K_{\large-\frac12-n-k-j}\left(\dfrac{|x|}{\sqrt3}\right).$$

[image: Plot]

Comment: @granularbastard 1) Beta-function; .2) will be fixed. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @granularbastard Done.

Comment: By numerical calculation I get different results compared to the solution of @Iknowit. Except for $x=0$ they are numerically identical. To avoid $0^0=1$ we can write $$I_{x=0}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}{\rm e}^{-a/3}}\sum _{n,k=0}^\infty \frac{\left(-a/3\right)^n \left(-b^2/3\right)^k}{n!(2k)!}\operatorname{B}\left(k+\frac{1}{2},k+n+\frac{1}{2}\right) $$

Comment: @granularbastard Thank you for the comments! Done.

Comment: @granularbastard [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum_%28k%3D0+to+199%29+%28%28%28-13.3%29%5Ek%2Fk%21+%281%2B%28randomreal%5B%5D-.5%29+10%5E-14%29%29+e%5E13.3%29) is a primitive model of the error accumulation for **double** numeric format. Possibly, extended numeric formats should be used

Comment: @granularbastard Fixed error.

Comment: @granularbastard Compare this place once more.

Comment: @granularbastard My argument is bigger

Comment: @granularbastard 0.170509816591357838239010052538851822186979853322081040397272

Comment: @granularbastard maybe, one of zero terms contains singularity.

Comment: @granularbastard I've checked a lot of times. The issue expression placed in the answer, you can test your fortune too.

Comment: @granularbastard Ready

Comment: Great. That works. Could you sort your equations? It seems there is a mixture of old and new formulas. As the old ones not worked (at least it was not possible to use them correctly) they could be moved to the end. Most commentaries here can also be removed.

Answer (score 2):

In a hurry, I pulled out of my head the equality of equations (1) & (2)  but had no time to write down all the steps or reduce to simpler functions that seems to be possible with low effort. I leave that for other users.

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3 t^2+1} {\rm exp}\left(\frac{a t^2+i b t}{3 t^2+1}+itx\right){\rm d}t\tag{1}\\
g(x)&=\frac{\pi e^{a/3}}{{\sqrt{3}}} \left(
\begin{array}{l}
 \begin{array}{l}
 \sum _{k,v=0}^\infty  \frac{c_-^k c_+^v}{k! (v!)^2}\left(\frac{-2x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^{(k+v)/2}W_{(v-k)/2,-(k+v+1)/2}\left(\frac{-2x}{\sqrt{3}}\right) & x<0 \\
 \sum _{k,v=0}^\infty  \frac{c_-^k c_+^v}{(k!)^2 v!}\left(\frac{2x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^{(k+v)/2}W_{(k-v)/2,-(k+v+1)/2}\left(\frac{2x}{\sqrt{3}}\right) & x>0 \\
 \sum _{k,v=0}^\infty  \frac{c_-^k c_+^v}{k! (v!)^2}(k+1)^{\overline{v}} & x=0 \\
\end{array}
\end{array}
\right)\tag{2}
\end{align}$$

with
$c_{\pm}=-\frac{a}{12}\pm\frac{b}{4 \sqrt{3}}$, [rising factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) $(\cdot)^{\overline{v}}$, and [Whittaker's $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker_function)

$$W_{(k-v)/2,-(k+v+1)/2}(x)=\sqrt{\dfrac{x^{k-v}}{e^x}}\sum _{s=0}^k \binom{k}{s} \frac{(v+1)^{\overline{s}}}{x^s}\tag{3}$$
A comparison of $f(x),g(x),|f(x)-g(x)|$ for $a=-20,b=-10$ reveals numerical insufficiencies. They are higher for the example given in the question $(a=-200,b=-100)$.

[image]

Comment: Good work, only a little bit lengthy expression.